# sound going mad

Tags: sound, asus, 23.10

I've installed Ubuntu 23.10 on a 2016 asus transformer mini. When it ran on Windows everything worked great and it didn't leave my desk ever since, which eliminates any hardware issues.

Usually my sound isn't working at all, sometimes it comes back only to bee interrupted by a random, loud, unending beep sound which stays even after I close all windows. When I connect headphones, the audio always works, but is also suddenly interrupted by the beep sound.

Any suggestions on what shall I do? I'll provide any necessary information.